# How to build CloudFormation template from multiple yml

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, stack, aws-cloudformation, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm trying to get this repo going here - https://github.com/mydatastack/google-analytics-to-s3.

A [link is provided to launch the AWS CloudFormation stack](https://eu-central-1.console.aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/home?region=eu-central-1#/stacks/create/review?templateURL=https://public-pipes-ga-s3-cloudformation-stack.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/631216aef6ab2824fc63572d1d3d5e6c.template) but it is no longer working as the S3 bucket containing the template is no longer active.

I have 2 questions about getting data pipeline running:

1. My first question would be what is `631216aef6ab2824fc63572d1d3d5e6c.template` and can I create it through the 3 .yml files in the [CloudFormation folder](https://github.com/mydatastack/google-analytics-to-s3/tree/master/cloudformation)?

I've tried to create a template through CloudFormation designer [image: collector-ga.yml template], `collector-ga.yml` but it fails. I think its because the Resources within the yml aren't available when creating a template just from `collector-ga`. I've also tried uploading the repo to s3 and creating a template from there but that was also unsuccessful.

2. How can I launch the stack from the repo? I've found very little information online so an explanation or a pointer to some relevant resources would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try `make deploy` command? What does it return? Any errors?

Comment: through AWS cli i get this `(local_SM) C:\Users\Me>aws cloudformation package --template Z:/Project/API/google-analytics-to-s3-master/cloudformation --s3-bucket ga2s3stack/cloudformation/ --output json > packaged-template.json
File association not found for extension .py

Invalid template path Z:/Dmyzer/API/google-analytics-to-s3-master/cloudformation` , I get this when pointing to both local and s3 .yml files. Updated the post for clarity but I think my main question is how do I recreate the template used to launch the stack from the github. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This repository doesn't use the "standard" CloudFormation resources, but it uses [AWS SAM](https://aws.amazon.com/serverless/sam/). You'll have to install the SAM CLI tool and use that to deploy the CloudFormation stack. If you run `sam deploy --guided` it will help you with the setup of the necessary S3 bucket etc on your AWS account. SAM will upload the necessary files, resolve the internal local links between the templates by updating them with the S3 URLs and construct a packaged.yml template which it will use to deploy the stack.

Also, check out the [AWS SAM user guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-getting-started.html) for more information.

Comment: Zizi96 - consider awarding the bounty to stijndepestel.